# Can't send this HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have made a popup box that displays a Google captcha from for example: `http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/ajax/rd%3Fsky%3Deeuiphp%26ludocid%3D6083833001863340802%26rdu%3DCNzphIbM6rECFWkGtAodP3UAGQ%26sig%3DaY3%26q%3Dtandl%25C3%25A4kare%252Cg%25C3%25B6teborg%2BSweden`

I then type in the captcha into the box within my program and send the info off to my next function below, it is supposed to submit the data to Google. I've tried to track it with Fiddler but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. The request just returns another captcha image.

In Fiddler I can see when I go to my browser and submit the request that it is of GET type, but how would I submit data to that? I've tried switching my POST to GET and so forth, but always get the same error, just another captcha image.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
public string submitGoogleCaptcha(string html, string captchaCode)
    {
        CookieContainer cookieCont = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest _wReq;
        HttpWebResponse _wResp;
        System.IO.StreamReader _sr;
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding _enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        string continueValue = Regex.Match(html, @"<input type=""hidden"" name=""continue"" value=""\s*(.+?)\s*"">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
        string idFromGoogle = Regex.Match(html, @"<input type=""hidden"" name=""id"" value=""\s*(.+?)\s*"">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;

        string _html = "";
        string postData = "continue=" + continueValue + "&id=" + idFromGoogle + "&captcha=" + captchaCode + "&submit=Submit";

        try
        {
            byte[] _data = _enc.GetBytes(postData);
            _wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/sorry/Captcha?");


            _wReq.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            _wReq.Referer = "http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(continueValue);
            _wReq.KeepAlive = true;


            _wReq.Method = "POST";
            _wReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            _wReq.ContentLength = _data.Length;
            _wReq.CookieContainer = cookieCont;
            _wReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            _wReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            System.IO.Stream _outStream = _wReq.GetRequestStream();
            _outStream.Write(_data, 0, _data.Length);
            _outStream.Close();
            _wResp = (HttpWebResponse)_wReq.GetResponse();
            _sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(_wResp.GetResponseStream());
            _html = _sr.ReadToEnd();
            _sr.Close();
            _wResp.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }


        return _html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try the code you posted, you get an exception.  You'd know that if you hadn't hidden all exceptions from yourself with `catch(Exception ee){}`.   The exception that you get is trying to tell you the server sent back a 503 error "Server not available".

I'd suggest you'd learn some fundamental exception handling principles.

Also, i see the request in Fiddler.

Comment: Does that error indicate that i am submitting to the wrong url?